# Ajax PHP variable passing

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, get

I've been following a tutorial that is meant to update content into a  loaded from a database.

My plan is to have various EP image covers load from a database, if they are clicked then a Div on the same page is populated with it's information (track title, artist, etc).

I've followed this tutorial amending it slightly to show the details that I want, it uses the _GET() method and the url changes as I expected to show the varible passing, however it seems to pass the mouse coordinates as well, not that this should be a problem, just not sure why it's doing it?

When the page loads it shows the images as expected, it appears to attempt a load on the content but doesn't seem to acheive it.

I'm sure it's something I've gone wrong adapting it where the buttons are the images and the value are hidden form fields, but I just couldn't find a tutorial that was as specific as to my needs.

Here's my code:

ajaxtest1.php:

```
<head>
//MySQL connection script

<script>
function showep(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("ep").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxtest2.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="ep">
Text text text
</div>
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM releases";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(!$result) die ("Database access failed: " .mysql_error());

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

  for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)


  {

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$id = $row [0];



echo '<form>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id .'" />';
echo '<input type="image" src="images/releases/' .$row[1] .'" width="150" height="150" onclick="showep(this.value)"/>';
echo '</form>';

  }
?>
</body>
```

ajaxtest2:
    
    //MYSQL connection script here.

```
if(!$result) die ("Database access failed: " .mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);


echo    "<pre>";
echo    "<img src='images/releases/"    .$row[1] . "' width= '150' height= '150' /><br />";
echo    "track title: "         .$row[2] . "<br />";
echo    "artist: "               .$row[3] . "<br />";
echo    "track length: "                .$row[4] . "<br />";
echo    "Remixes by: " .$row[5] . " " . $row[6] . " " . $row[7] . "<br />";
echo    "Released: "                      .$row[8] . " ";
echo    "</pre>";

mysql_close($db_server);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please use mysqli_ instead of mysql_! mysql_ is deprecated.

Comment: if you are using php 5.5 or upper version please use mysqli_* function or pdo following link will help you http://www.tricksofit.com/2013/10/difference-between-mysql-pdo

Comment: Ok thanks, would this be the problem with the code working?

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you are passing `this.value` from the onclick handler of the `<input type="image">`, whereas the id has only been defined on the `<input type="hidden">` element. Try adding the value attribute to the `<input type="image">` as well.

Another source for concern is the url changing: this is something that should not happen in AJAX calls, and if it does, this is an indication that an AJAX call is not being performed. In this case, this is because an `<input type="image">` behaves like a submit button, passing the values in the form along with the coordinates of the point where the user clicked on the image. The button is clicked, the AJAX call is initiated, and the form is submitted before the AJAX call can return. Since the `form` tag does not have an `action` attribute, the current page (served by ajaxtest1.php) is assumed, ajaxtest1.php loads, and the call to ajaxtest2.php is never heard from again.

To keep the form from submitting, you can do one of two things. First, you can instruct the form not to submit, by changing the form tag to `<form onsubmit="return false;">`. Second, and perhaps easier, is to recognize you don't need a form in the first place, since you are only performing an AJAX call. To do this, all you need is a regular `img` tag with an onclick handler.

tl;dr - Change:

```
echo '<form>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id .'" />';
echo '<input type="image" src="images/releases/' .$row[1] .'" width="150" height="150" onclick="showep(this.value)"/>';
echo '</form>';
```

to:

```
echo '<img src="images/releases/' .$row[1] .'" width="150" height="150" onclick="showep(' . $id .')"/>';
```

and you will perform an AJAX call instead of a form submit.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've changed my code to reflect the idea of just processing the image and the Ajax call is now working fine, however it is failing to pass the value of `$id` through to ajaxtest2.php. I have tried `_post` and `_request`. How do I send the variable of `$id` through to ajaxtest2.php?

Comment: Ok I've been around the code in several different ways experimenting with Sessions as well as the various different GET and POST methods and I keep ending up with an undefined variable. I can't seem to send the ID value through to ajaxtest2.php. It just doesn't seem to pick it up weather its a form or just the image to click on with the javascript. I can not see where this is going wrong.

Comment: Can you show what code you are using? Actually, `$_GET` and `$_POST` are not methods but array variables. Since you are using ajax to `GET` `ajaxtest2.php?q=<id>`, the code you should use to retrieve the id in ajaxtest2.php would be something like `$id = $_GET['q'];`.